# How to call ansible yml file from other file?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am new to ansible and, I am trying to call my_task.yml from my_plybk.yml.

The content of my_playbk.yml is as follow:

```
---
   - hosts: localhost
     gather_facts: no

     tasks:
       - include my_tasks.yml
```

The content of my_task.yml is as follow.

```
- hosts: localhost
     tasks:
       - name: Run the below script
         command: sh myscript.sh
```

Content of myscript.sh

```
echo "Hello"
```

below is the error which I am getting.

```
ERROR! A malformed block was encountered while loading a block
```

Comment: The `tasks:` line in `my_task.yml` is indented too much. should be directly under `hosts`

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem could be the extra spacing in your `my_plybk.yaml` file.

It should be arranged like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - include: my_tasks.yml
```

Also, there were missing colon after "include".

Same applicable to the `my_tasks.yml` file:

```
- name: Run the below script
  command: sh myscript.sh
```

Also, please note in the text above that your included file should contain only list of tasks, without "hosts" or "tasks" keyword.

Please note that Ansible and yaml-files in general are very sensitive on how you arrange rows and spaces.

Comment: @Vivek please try once again with new changes